# Url rewrite issue not getting current session (getPrincipal()) for redirected url

Tags: spring-mvc, url-rewriting, spring-security

I have rewrited url
from: `http://www.xyz.com/Sample/showSamples-ASA21DS`
to: `http://www.xyz.com/Sample/showSamples.do?sampleId=ASA21DS`

using urlRewrite.xml

```
<urlrewrite>

<rule>
    <from>^/http://www.xyz.com/Sample/showSamples-ASA21DS</from>
    <to>http://www.xyz.com/Sample/showSamples.do?sampleId=ASA21DS</to>
</rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

But, I dont get current session for this new url..
For this,

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()
```

i m getting null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to make sure the new request is still going through the Spring Security filters.  This question is actually on the official FAQ page: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq/faq.html#faq-no-filters-no-context

Comment: I m new for spring and I read that FAQ page.. but i didn't get it. Can u please explain, how to check request is going through spring security filters. I am using annotations there is no any spring security filters. Thanks.. :)

Comment: If you rewritten request is not going through the Spring Security filters, it won't get the security context.  Confirm that the same security configuration you have for the original URL is also being used for the second URL.